# I got this error when deserializing XML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I got this error at the time of deserializing my XML.
Could you help me find what's wrong, I've been working on this for several hours. It must be some little detail that I'm missing or maybe the root is the problem.

> Error: “There is an error in xml document (1, 40)”

Here´s my class:

```
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("return")]
    public class Response
    {
        private string ticket { get; set; };
        private string name { get; set; };
        private string profile { get; set; };
        private string companyId { get; set; };       
        private string storeId { get; set; };
        private string terminalId { get; set; };
        private string accountNo { get; set; };
        private bool postae { get; set; };
        private bool postaeproduct { get; set; };
    }
```

This is the XML that I tried to deserialize

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
     <ns2:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices/">
       <return>
       <xml>
       <ticket>123456789</ticket>
       <name>TEST</name>
       <profile>Sale</profile>
       <companyId>2</companyId>
       <storeId>1</storeId>
       <terminalId>1</terminalId>
       <accountNo>0000000001</accountNo>
       <postae>true</postae>
       <postaeproduct>true</postaeproduct>
       </xml> 
       </return>
     </ns2:loginResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And finally the method to deserialize

```
private T Deserializa<T>(byte[] xmlByteData)
        {       XmlSerializer ds = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xmlByteData);
                object d = ds.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                return (T)d;
            }
```

**UPDATE**

This is how the chain that is processed in the deserialize method looks like:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><S:Body><ns2:loginResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://webservices/\"><return>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;ticket&gt;123456789&lt;/ticket&gt;&lt;name&gt;TEST&lt;/name&gt;&lt;profile&gt;Sale&lt;/profile&gt;\n&lt;companyId&gt;2&lt;/companyId&gt;\n&lt;storeId&gt;1&lt;/storeId&gt;\n&lt;terminalId&gt;1&lt;/terminalId&gt;\n&lt;accountNo&gt;0000000001&lt;/accountNo&gt;\n&lt;postae&gt;true&lt;/postae&gt;\n&lt;postaeproduct&gt;true&lt;/postaeproduct&gt;\n&lt;/xml&gt;\n</return></ns2:loginResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>"
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: Those hyphens make the XML invalid...

Comment: what hyphens?  I agree though the xml must be the issue

Comment: Without exact data you have it is not possible to know what wrong with it. Please [edit] post to show real [MCVE] including the data. Preferably you convert your bytes to plain text first so we can see value as a `string`.

Comment: @JohnLord OP edited post to remove them... Hopefully we'll see [MCVE] soon too.

Comment: Sorry those hyphens were added when I copied from the clipboard, it's kind of weird they're really not there in the code

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pf4duh) that reproduces the error, since OP apparently is too busy to provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues I see here, both with the XML and with the class setup.

- These namespaces don't seem to be handled in the code:

```
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
     <ns2:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices/">
```

- Your root `return` object has another nested object called `xml` in it, so you should add an `xml` class in there, like this:

```
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("return")]
    public class Response
    {
        private Xml xml { get; set; };
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("xml")]
    private class Xml
    {
        private string ticket { get; set; };
        private string name { get; set; };
        private string profile { get; set; };
        private string companyId { get; set; };       
        private string storeId { get; set; };
        private string terminalId { get; set; };
        private string accountNo { get; set; };
        private bool postae { get; set; };
        private bool postaeproduct { get; set; };
    }
```

Comment: Note that OP removed hyphens... Otherwise while good suggestion I don't think OP's code get that far - "invalid XML" errors generally happen before actual deserialization to concrete type can start...

Comment: Good point. The issue is probably still with the XML itself. I do believe once they get past the XML issues, they will run into another issue involving the class nesting, which can be  fixed by the above solution.

Comment: @Christine does the `private class Xml` need the `[Serializable()]` attribute?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ yes, I've added it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm sure some of the original problem is none of the quotes are escaped and neither are the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to deal with a lot of Xml from API's at a job and we frequently had problems with Xml Serializer.

If it works for you than fine, but if not I created a project called Xml Mirror that makes it pretty simple to create Xml C# parsers (and writers) using reflection (get it mirror / reflection?).

https://github.com/DataJuggler/XmlMirror

And here is a video I made a couple weeks ago for a similar issue:

Create XML Parsers with Xml Mirror:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGRWDlzVq6s